# Exchange 365 - Reply from catch any

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

I got outlook 365 for business for myself. I've created "Catch All" rule for any email to my domain to my personal email.

I want to be able to reply from original email address as if it existed in domain. How to set it up?

---

Example:

I registered to RandomStore using randomstore@mydomain.com email and read it when I login to personal@mydomain.com

How to reply to their emails from randomstore@mydomain.com?
If I try to do it now I get "You don't have permission to send messages from this mailbox." error. This email does not exits in domain so I cannot set "SendAs" for this email.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange Online?
Based on my knowledge, it is not feasible. This should cause security issue.

Comment: It would help if you explained *why* it's not feasible (hint: The SendAs permission applies to mailboxes, not email addresses).